# editing output of a Keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I have a Convolutional Neural Network in the shape of the simple LeNet-5. I am using the modified NIST data set as my inputs

[image: Here is a picture of the structure]

Here's my question: I want to take the output of conv2d and divide everything by 2 or some other number before inputting it to the max_pooling2d layer. Then I want to do the same with all the other layers: take the output of max_pooling divide it by 2 before inputting it to conv2d_1 and so on. I am aware of the inline commands to edit the layers but is there one for this situation? OR is there another way of doing this with Keras? I could make the whole network again from scratch so I can edit the outputs with ease but it would be much less efficient.

Comment: You can use the `tf.keras.layers.Multiply` layer. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Multiply).